# How to align all element (such as text box) in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I've tried to allocate each element into fix size of 18 column, however in the output still doesnt seems to align...? How to make these perfectly align on each element?

[alignment issue sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAcKR.png)

```
layout = [
        [
            sg.Text('Camera Device', size=(18,1), justification='left', font=("Arial", "10" )),
            sg.InputCombo(["Logitech", "Xiaomi"], enable_events=True, key='-COMBO_CAMERA-', size=(18,1)),
            sg.Button('Reset', size=(18,1), key='-BUTTON_RESET-', font=("Arial", "10" , "bold")),
        ],
        [
            sg.Text('_' * 90),
        ],
        [
            sg.Text('Number of Video(s)', size=(18,1), justification='left', font=("Arial", "10" )),
            sg.Text(video_count, size=(18,1), justification='center', key='-DISPLAY_VIDEO_COUNT-', text_color='black'),
            sg.FolderBrowse(size=(18,1), font=("Arial", "10", "bold")),
        ],
        [
            sg.Text('Configuration', size=(18,1), justification='left', font=("Arial", "10" )),
            sg.InputText(size=(18,1), justification='center', key='-DISPLAY_REFERENCE_NAME-', text_color='black'),
            sg.Combo(["Low", "Medium", "High"], enable_events=True, key='-COMBO_SENSITIVITY-', size=(16,1)),

        ],
        [
            sg.Button('Run', size=(18,1), disabled=False, key='-BUTTON_RUN-', font=("Arial", "10" , "bold")),
            sg.Text('{}/{}'.format(completed_task, total_task), size=(18,1), justification='center', key='-DISPLAY_PROGRESS-', text_color='black'),
            sg.Text(estimated_time, justification='center', size=(18,1), key='-DISPLAY_WAITING_TIME-', text_color='black'),
            sg.Button('Export Result', disabled=False, font=("Arial", "10" , "bold"), size=(18,1))
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: First, use same mono-space font for all elements, like `sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))`. Specified option `font` when initialize element use different font as not specified. Different elements maybe with different width and/or height. The only way is to put all elements on same column in a `sg.Column`, then initial element with `expand_x=True`.